# Headers in Tomcat

Tags: apache, security, tomcat, header

I want to set two headers at Tomcat level. Setting these on Apache level will affect my applications. 
Below two headers

```
Set-Cookie HttpOnly;
Secure Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: Can you modify application code? Then you could install a ServletFilter that sets these headers.

Comment: No, It should be set from infrastructure level.

Comment: Are you running Apache `httpd` on top of Tomcat?

Comment: yes, running httpd on top of tomcat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTTP Header Security Filter like this :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>HTTP Header Security Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
    <param-value>31536000</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>hstsIncludeSubDomains</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>HTTP Header Security Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

For details read the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter).